# Dispatch action not working with createUserWithEmailAndPassword firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I am using Redux and Firebase (i.e. Auth, Firestore) together, additionally using Expo as I haven't had experience with just React Native itself. Trying to setup the signUp and logIn actions but it does not work. I have searched high and low for examples and issues and read the docs and seen that others are doing the same way as I am doing it but I just can't get it working. And not getting any error message or just anything is a real bummer.

I haven't started using the Redux part yet as I'm trying to work the base of the authentication with Firebase.

Odd thing is, I used these codes 2 years ago in another project and it worked fine.

Appreciate any inputs please, thank you

App.js:

```js
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import authReducer from './src/redux/reducers/auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authState: authReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <The rest of the App />
    </Provider>
  );
```

Actions for auth.js: (Made comments in codes to show where it breaks)

```js
import firebase from '../../api/';

const db = firebase.firestore();

export const signUp = (email, password, name) => {
  let signUpResponse;

  // DOES REACH HERE

  // This does not work
  return async dispatch => {
    // DOES NOT ENTER HERE AT ALL.

    await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) // Could have broken here
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res); // Doesn't even print this
        signUpResponse = res.user;

        firebase
          .auth()
          .currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName: name })
          .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_USER, user: signUpResponse.displayName });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('err.message', err.message));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        let message = 'An error has occured!';

        let errorPresent =
          err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use' ||
          err.code === 'auth/invalid-email' ||
          err.code === 'auth/weak-password';

        if (errorPresent) {
          message = 'Invalid Credentials!';
        }

        throw new Error(message);
      });
  };

  // This works from Firebase Auth docs
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCredential => {
      // Signed in
      var user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch(error => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });
};
```

Reducer for auth.js:

```js
import { GET_USER } from '../constants/index';

const initialState = {
  name: ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.user
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Firebase init:

```js
import ENV from '../../env';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';
require('firebase/firestore');

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log('init firebase success'); // Successful here at every run

  firebase.initializeApp(ENV().firebaseConfig);
}

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, learned and used Redux Toolkit. Closing this now.